# .NET/MYSQL RDS: Intermittent Issue A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception, he message or signature supplied for verification has been altered

Tags: mysql, .net, rds, sspi

Seeing this error seemingly randomly (never been able to recreate):

Intermittent A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception, he message or signature supplied for verification has been altered

.net 4.5 connecting to MYSQL 5.7.21 on RDS.

Is this an issue on our end or on AWS' end?

Comment: We're seeing the exact same issue in the same set up. Did you ever find a solution?